# GloVe dot product optimized for non-comutative data whilst the operation itself being commutative

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec, mathematics, stanford-nlp

To my current knowledge, GloVe word vectors dot product are optimized to be the

w_i ⋅ w_j = log⁡(P(ⅈ|j))

The probability being computed from a cooccurance matrix. However, dot product is a commutative operation, whilst the log probablity isn't. Is this issue being adressed in GloVe? Am I missing something?